# Parallel addition of the attribute of every item

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have a DynamoDB table

`Hash | Range | Value
1    |  1    |   1
1    |  2    |   3
2    |  1    |   1`

I want a sum of Values for a given Hash, and I want to do it in parallel.
How can I ensure that every Item gets summed exactly once?
Currently, I'm trying to do it by scanning and passing "TheLastEvaluatedKey" to another worker, who scans it and passes "TheLastEvaluatedKey" to another worker and so on.
However, it feels wrong, like I'm missing something.
Please let me know if there is another way, or maybe my approach will do.
As a side question: what is the best way to pass 'LastEvaluatedKey' between workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [parallel scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScanParallelScan) to scan segments of your table in parallel.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how had I missed it.